# (xcode objective-c) Array - finding a center of a object in an array

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, nsarray

I'm pretty nooby when it comes to `Xcode` but here goes.

I have an `NSArray` with 5 `UIImageView`'s, I have a script which will pick a random `UIImageView`, but I need it to then output the center of the image that was chosen.
My code looks like this:

```
NSMutableArray *Invader = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[Invader addObject:H1];
[Invader addObject:H2];
[Invader addObject:H3];
[Invader addObject:H4];
[Invader addObject:H5];
```

Then like this to choose where to move a new `UIImageView` to:

```
if (FIRE1 == YES){
    NSObject *Inv1 = [Invader randomObject]; //randomObject picks a random Invader
    InvaderBullet1.hidden = NO;
    InvaderBullet1.center = CGPointMake(Inv1.center.x, Inv1.center.y)
}
```

The error it's giving me is `Property 'center' not found on object of type 'NSObject *'`

I'm hoping this makes sense to anyone and that anyone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing like "Xcode array". Xcode is an IDE…

Comment: @septi: He probably added (xcode) to the title to denote that it's Xcode related question (though that's what tags are for) and it has no relation to Array.

Comment: This question is not related to Xcode at all. You can write iOS or OS X application in vim if you like.

Comment: It doesn't help that i'm a noob at xcode but I need this code to be able to pick a random object from the array and output it's center to the InvaderBullet1

Comment: Show us the code for Invader.

Comment: @dasdom: You can obviously see he's been here for 9 days (and probably new to Objective-C / iOS programming) and makes a relation between the IDE and his programming (especially since everyone writes iOS applications in Xcode). We've all done that some time when we were new...

Comment: @LordZsolt no that is not what the `xcode` tag is for. The `xcode` tag is used for issues that you are having with the `xcode IDE` itself not issues you are having within `xcode`. If they want to add into their question they are using the `xcode IDE` that is perfectly fine as long as they don't use the tag. You don't need to do objective-c coding in the `xcode IDE` I have used `notepad++` before.

Comment: @Popeye You're missing the point that he's probably new to SO so he can't tag his questions correctly and probably new to programming so he thinks it might be IDE related...

Comment: @LordZsolt I was making a point about your first comment saying that the question was related to `xcode` so instead of putting it in the title they should use the `xcode` tag, that is wrong, since it has nothing to do with `xcode` so having it in the title or the question is perfectly fine as it doesn't add another question to that tag that has nothing to do with that tag. I would expect a newbie to tag incorrectly but not someone with your rep so please don't advise to use tag when they shouldn't

Comment: Do you get the error for `Inv1` or `InvaderBullet1` or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSObject obviously doesn't have a center property. Though you're not adding NSObjects to your array, you're adding (I assume) UIImageViews. So if you're adding UIImages, you can remove UIImages as well.

```
  if (FIRE1 == YES){
    NSObject *Inv1 = [Invader randomObject];
    if ([Inv1 isKindOfClass:[UIImageView Class]]) //randomObject picks a random Invader
         ((UIImageView*)InvaderBullet1).hidden = NO;
         ((UIImageView*)InvaderBullet1).center = CGPointMake(Inv1.center.x, Inv1.center.y)
    }
```

Comment: I'm adding UIImageView's to the array

Comment: Edited the answer, though I dislike the fact that you didn't make any effort to try and customise my code.

Comment: I have been tweaking it in my xcode and have got it working, Thanks for the help ^^

Comment: @LordZsolt that's not the way this works you don't give partial answer that they need to tweak and customize, you should give full answer to the question they have asked otherwise there just is no point in you giving an answer.

Comment: @Popeye I had to say that It was a UIImageView rather than a UIImage, then commented and tweaked it in my xcode.

Comment: @Popeye I know, I mistakingly wrote a partial answer (reflected by the fact that I updated it right after).

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to specify the correct type for your variable:

```
if (FIRE1 == YES){
    UIImageView *Inv1 = [Invader randomObject]; //randomObject picks a random Invader
    InvaderBullet1.hidden = NO;
    InvaderBullet1.center = CGPointMake(Inv1.center.x, Inv1.center.y)
}
```

This is assuming that your `randomObject` method (looks like a category method on `NSArray`) has a return type of `id`. If its return type is `NSObject *` then you need to do a cast:

```
UIImageView *Inv1 = (UIImageView *)[Invader randomObject]; //randomObject picks a random Invader
```

(Minor note: I recommend to stick to the established naming conventions. In this case: variables usually start with a lower-case character. You're doing other people that need/want to work with your code a favor.)